# Jenkins Promoted Builds -- promotion UI missing?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have set up an awesome Jenkins server and am now trying out the Promoted Builds plugin, but am having trouble getting it to do anything. I want to set up manual promotion so that I can click a button and copy the artifacts (using the Copy Artifacts plugin) to another server. My promote config looks like:

[image: My promote config]

And when I click promote on a build, I get:

[image: What happens when I click promote]

...which is not so useful. There doesn't seem to be a "do stuff!" button.

It seems like it should look more like [this](https://vimeo.com/69234678):

[image: What should happen, I think?]

...but it doesn't. What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem and I noticed that if a build was run when the job didn't have any promotion set up, then the result is what you have. Try to re-run the job now, after setting the promotions and it will be enabled (at least it did for me).

Comment: Thanks, that was totally it.